# Google direction services.How to detect if geo location is disabled in the browser 

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If a user has disabled the location feature or if he uses a non geo supported feature.

How to do this programatically? This will get executed,if i enable geo location in my browser ,if i do not enable,i want some other code to get executed.Where i put that other code which will be executed when i do not enable or use non supported browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) to sniff out whether the browser supports geolocation and then take the appropriate action.

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
  //do geolocation/gmaps stuff
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

You can even load shims to give the geolocation functionality to browsers which don't support it. There are examples in the [modernizer documentation section](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/).

e.g.

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep : 'geo.js',
  nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

--Edit

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="modernizer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=true"></script>
<script>

var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() { 

  if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
  // Do the geolocation  
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initializeGeo, handle_error);          
  } else {
  // No geolocation path
  initializeNonGeo();
  } 
}

function handle_error(err) {
  alert("Geolocation could not be run");
  if (err.code == 1) {
    alert("user denied");// user said no!
  }
  initializeNonGeo();
}

function initializeGeo() {
  alert("has geolocation");
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
} 

function initializeNonGeo() {
   alert("no geolocation"); //do non geo stuff.
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd probably rename your initilize method to initializeGeo or something like that, and then create an initilize method something like: `function initialize() { 
    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
       initiliseGeo();
    } else {
       initialiseNonGeo
    } 
}`

Comment: :Should i use any library for that modernizr to get it working.You can n't call two functions on one event

Comment: You should just need the Modernizer library http://www.modernizr.com/download/ (you probably just need to check the extra Geolocation API box) and the google maps API. You would just call one method but then use an if else statement to call the appropriate methods.

Comment: Just leave the defaults in extra. The HTML5 shim, modernizer load and the CSS.

Comment: :I inserted a alert in bot if and else ,both did not alert,that means that plug in is not working.Do i have any web link from where that plug in gets loaded.

Comment: I've added a full example which I have tried and works. All you need to do is put the modernizer.js file you created at the same level as the HTML file.

Comment: @Paul Irish:Can you pls help me out in this

Comment: One last go! I've added the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initializeGeo, handle_error);   callback in case this is what you were looking for. If the browser supports geolocation but the user denies it it will go into the non gelocation path.